# PHP dynamic breadcrumb script creates wrong URL after switching to PHP 8.0

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

I'm using a PHP script to create a dynamic breadcrumb navigation. I found it several years ago in another forum where it was originally posted in 2006. I updated it by removing some deprecated functions and it worked well so far. It creates the crumbs from the page URL:

```
$path = $this->_homepath;
$html ='';
$html .= '<a href="https://www.myhomepage.com">Start</a>';

$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$partscount = count($parts);
for($i = 1; $i < ($partscount - 1); $i++) { 
  $path .= $parts[$i] . '/';
  $title = $parts[$i];
  
  if ($this->_usereplacements == true) { 
    reset($this->_replacements);
    foreach($this->_replacements as $search => $replace) {
        $title = str_replace($search, $replace, $title);
    }
  }
  
  if ($this->_replaceunderlines == true) { 
    $title = str_replace('_', ' ', $title);
  }
  
  if ($this->_ucfirst == true) { 
    $title = ucfirst($title);
  }
  
  if ($this->_ucwords == true) { 
    $title = ucwords($title);
  }
  
  $html .= $this->_separator . '<a href="' . $path . '">' . $title . '</a>';
}
```

The current page title, i.e. the last element of the bradcrumb, is generated as follows:

```
$title = '';
if ($title == '') { 
  $title = $parts[$partscount-1];
  
  if ($this->_usereplacements == true) { 
   reset($this->_replacements);
   foreach($this->_replacements as $search => $replace) {
        $title = str_replace($search, $replace, $title);
   }
  }
 
  if ($this->_removeextension == true) { 
    $title = substr($title, 0, strrpos($title, '.'));
  }
  
  if ($this->_replaceunderlines == true) { 
    $title = str_replace('_', ' ', $title);
  }
  
  if ($this->_ucfirst == true) { 
    $title = ucfirst($title);
  }
  
  if ($this->_ucwords == true) { 
    $title = ucwords($title);
  }
}
$html .= $this->_separator . '<b>' . $title . '</b>';
```

I only copied relevant parts of the script and spared eg. the function declarations.

After switching from PHP 7.4 to 8.0 I found that the script is messing up a bit. Consider a page with this url: `https://www.myhomepage.com/site1/site2/site3`

For the crumbs of `site1` the script is now generating the URL `https://www.myhomepage.com/site1/site2/site1` insted of `https://www.myhomepage.com/site1/`, whereas for `site2` it shows `https://www.myhomepage.com/site1/site2/site1/site2` instead of `https://www.myhomepage.com/site1/site2/`. As you can see, the whole path `https://www.myhomepage.com/site1/site2/` is always added as a prefix before the actual path of the crumb.

I haven't found a solution yet despite looking over this thing for two days. I suppose there have been some changes in PHP 8.0 which causes this behaviour, but I haven't found any clues in the incompatibility list (https://www.php.net/manual/de/migration80.php). I printed `§path` and `$title` and they look like they should. When echoing `$html` after each iteration in the for loop it shows already the wrong URLs. That's why I think that probably the for loop is the problem here. Do you have any suggestions?

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] results might differ between the two PHP versions. Check for any difference.

Comment: What does `$parts` look like? This `if ($title == '') {` seems redundant since you set `$title` to empty string in the line before.

Comment: @OMiShah Not in my case though. I get the same result regardless which PHP version I use.

Comment: @brombeer It looks as expected: An array with n elements where n being the number of sites depending on the URL. The [0] element of the array is empty, which was also the case when I still used PHP 7.4. The `if ($title == '')` statement is because I left out a function in my original post which reads the title from the page content, e.g. from its html header. I'm not using this in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to figure out what causes the strange behaviour of the script. In the declaration of the breadcrumb constructing function there is `$this->_homepath = '/';`. Later on I assign `$path = $this->_homepath;`. When I echo $path its empty instead of showing the aforementioned "/". So I directly set `$path = '/';` and now everything works again as it should.